# What is the output created when constructing an instance of an object

Tags: java

Suppose the following code runs without error:

[image]

And suppose that in some other class we have a main method: `A var1 = new C();`

I was given these two questions which I answered wrong:

**1) What output will be created by constructing that instance of C?**

My answer to this was *some*, and I thought it was this because it says `new C();`, so it creates a new C object and in the constructor in that class it prints *some*. But I was wrong, the correct answer was one here some. This doesn't make sense to me, and I don't really know how that was possible.

**2) which method is called if the method call `((B) var1).report()` is used.**

My answer to this was the method report in the B class. I thought this was the correct answer because var1 is casted with B so I assumed that it will use the method in the B class. But I was wrong for this as well. The correct answer was the method in the C class. This doesn't make sense to me either.

This was very confusing and I don't really know how to get those answers. If someone could explain to me what exactly is happening and how they got that answer that would be really appreciated.

Comment: follow a tutorial about constructor chain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer 1).** You were partly right that the constructor for C will be called, but don't forget that a child object will always call a constructor on its parent. If the child class does not specify which constructor to call, then the no-args constructor will be used.

So in the constructor for C, the compiler added a call to super(), which called the constructor on B, and once again the compiler added a call to super(), which called the constructor on A. So the whole chain ended up being A() -> B() -> C().

**Answer 2).** Even though arg1 was cast to a B, it is still an instance of C. So polymorphism will result in a call to the report() method on C.

This may be easier to visualize if you rename A to Animal, B to Mammal, and C to Dog. So you could refer to an instance of dog as either an Animal or a Mammal and it would be correct, but it doesn't change the fact that it is still a dog. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks hooda that makes so much more sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

They got that answer from the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html), section [8.8.7. Constructor Body](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7):

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor
>   invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the
>   primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins
>   with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of
>   the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

And section [8.4.8.1. Overriding (by Instance Methods)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1):

```
class Point {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    void move(int dx, int dy) { x += dx; y += dy; }
}
class SlowPoint extends Point {
    int xLimit, yLimit;
    void move(int dx, int dy) {
        super.move(limit(dx, xLimit), limit(dy, yLimit));
    }
    static int limit(int d, int limit) {
        return d > limit ? limit : d < -limit ? -limit : d;
    }
}
```

> *Here, the class SlowPoint overrides the declarations of method move of class Point with its own move method, which limits the distance
>   that the point can move on each invocation of the method. When the
>   move method is invoked for an instance of class SlowPoint, the
>   overriding definition in class SlowPoint will always be called, **even
>   if the reference to the SlowPoint object is taken from a variable
>   whose type is Point**.*

Answer (score 0):

The first thing each constructor (ctor) does, whether it is explicitly written or not, is to call a superclass ctor (if it isn't specified explicitly, then the one with no arguments is called). So C's ctor calls B's, which calls A's, which calls the ctor of Object (the superclass of A, even though A isn't explicitly declared as "A extends Object"). The Object ctor doesn't print anything out. It returns to A, which prints "one", and returns to B, which prints "here", and returns to C, which prints "some".

```
one
here
some
```

In the case of the call to `report()`, the cast to B doesn't matter. Methods in Java are dispatched on the actual runtime type of the object, and in this case, the `var1` object is of type `C`. So when the method is called, the JVM looks at the actual object and find the `C.report()` method. That's the one that gets dispatched.

The compile-time type of the object was `B`, and if the decision about which method to call had to be made at compile time, it would have picked `A.report()` (since the `report()` method isn't overridden in `B`), but the method is found at runtime, when the actual type of the object is known.

(The decision of which *overload* of an overloaded method (two methods with the same name but different parameters) to call is made at compile time, but *overridden* methods are chosen between at runtime. There are languages which decide overloads at runtime as well, but Java is not one of them.)